# file signature 0A 0A 0A

Tags: java, excel

I made an account on this site because of a problem I've been struggling with for a few days now. I'm trying to make a java program that can login to a secured site and download a certain Excel file (using valid credentials, nothing illegal!)

However, when I try to open the excel file, I get a `NotOle2FileException`. The file I'm trying to download/read is an excel file, but it's hosted on a SharePoint environment that automatically opens it with the Excel Web App... The header signature I'm getting is `0x6C6D74683C0A0A0A` and should be `0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0` (<- Excel OLE2 format)...

does anyone have any idea what the file signature i'm getting refers to ? Does it have to do anything with the excel file being embedded on the site in some way?

Codewise I'm trying this:

```
URLConnection uc = anchor.click().getUrl().openConnection();
    Workbook workbook;
    workbook = getWorkbook(uc);

    private Workbook getWorkbook(URLConnection uc) throws IOException {
    Workbook workbook = null;
    System.out.println(uc.getURL());
    if (uc.getURL().toString().endsWith("xls")) {
       workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(uc.getInputStream());
    } else if (uc.getURL().toString().endsWith("xlsx")) {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(uc.getInputStream());
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The specified path is not an excel file");
    }

    return workbook;
    }
```

The anchor refers to the element on the website that links to the excel file (can't be hardcoded since I want to be able to download different files, depending on user input) basicly: the `href` attribute of the anchor links to an url ending on .xlsx

EDIT: so the signature would be a htmlpage, but when trying to save it as HtmlPage i'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.UnexpectedPage cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
```

Comment: You're getting a HTML page back. The hex translates in `lmth<`. IMHO you should try to download the file locally as a first step (or debug) and then open it.

Comment: any idea how i can extract the excel file from the html page ?
My program works fine if i download the excel file and read it locally, but i'm trying to let my program download it for me ... when i tried to save it as an excel file, it got corrupted (probably cuz i was saving a html page as an excel file)

Comment: You're creating a HSSFWorkbook when the string ends with xlsx and an XSSFWorkbook when string ends with xls, which is incorrect - it should be the other way around.

Comment: Woops, thanks for that one! switched them around :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, thanks to the comment saying it was a Html page !

Basicly i put it in an 'UnexpectedPage' object first, using the .getInputStream as inputstream for the excel file. Just had to add 2 lines of code :)

Comment: You should add the two lines of code you added to fix the problem- it may be useful for someone in the future.